# Retrieve Datasource Statistics on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, monitoring, sqldatasource

How would i programmatically retrieve usage statistics for datasources deployed on [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/)? Its [possible](http://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/monitoring_jdbc_connection_pool_glassfish) with [GlassFish](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/oracle-glassfish-server/index.html), however lost on how to do the same for JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that via JMX.

For a start, go to http://localhost:8080/jmx-console and search for the JNDI name of the data source. This will show ~ 3 mbeans per datasource from where you can then get the statistics.

Of course you can get at the data programmatically - just follow the AMX example in your glassfish link on how to talk to the MBeanServer - of course you need to change the ObjectNames and Attribut names to reflect the JBoss ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JavaMelody](http://javamelody.googlecode.com) to have statistics on sql or http requests, jdbc connections and more.